# Can I accept my student's solution of $\lim _{x \to \infty} \ln x-2x$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

> > Can I accept my student's solution of $$\lim_{ x \to \infty} \ln x-2x$$

I gave the above limit to my student. This is the way she has done.
$$\begin{aligned}
L= & \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln x-2 x=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}-2\right) \\
& \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}-2=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}-2=-2 \: \text{(By L'Hopital's Rule)}\\
\Rightarrow \quad & L=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} x \times-2=-\infty
\end{aligned}$$

But I suggested this way:
$$\begin{gathered}
x=\frac{1}{t} \\
\Rightarrow L=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0^{+}}-\ln t-\frac{2}{t} \\
\Rightarrow \quad L=-\lim _{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2+t \ln t}{t} \\
\lim _{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} t \ln t=0 \: \text{(Again by L'Hopital's Rule)}\\
\Rightarrow L=-\infty
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: Your student's solution appears sound.

Comment: The part $\lim \frac{\ln x}{x} =\lim \frac{1}{x}$ is a bit awkward though. For instance, $\lim \frac{\ln x}{x} =\lim \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is also true.

Comment: @Gary that's by L'Hopital's

Comment: Ok, I see now. In that case the two solutions are virtually the same.

Comment: @all i came to know that student's solution is fine by Alex Oritz...but is it applicable universally for any problem on limits or are there any exceptions where my student's method will not work?

Comment: If anything, you might want to state explicitly that the limit of a product is the product of the two separate limits, but other than that, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I find your student’ solution straightforward and intuitive. Commends attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we are being really pedantic, I think both solutions have a small "gap." Either solution wants to use a result of calculus which says something like the following:

(M) If $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$, then $a_nb_n\to ab$.

(S) If $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$, then $a_n + b_n\to a + b$.

Your student would like to use (M) because they know $\ln x/x -2 \to -2$, and $x\to \infty$, so by (M), we should have the limit $-\infty$. Your solution would like to use (S) because you know $t\ln t\to 0$, and $2$ is constant, so by (S), $2 + t\ln t\to 2$. (I presume this is what you had in mind.)

The thing is, the formal laws (M) and (S) work fine when $a$ and $b$ are both finite real numbers. When either of $a$ or $b$ is $\pm\infty$, things get more complicated, and so I would say both solutions need some more explanation as to how they get the final answer. If anything, I think your student's solution is clearer because it's easier to justify that (M) holds when exactly one of the the limits $a$ or $b$ is finite and nonzero, and the other is $+\infty$.

The problem I have with your solution is that you know $t\ln t \to 0$, but you are also dividing by $t$, so overall we are still in a situation where the fully written out solution needs something like an appeal to L'Hospital's rule, or an estimate of the size of $\ln t + 2/t$ as $t\to 0^+$.

Comment: Small addenum: (M) holds when one of the limits is infinite provided the other is finite and *nonzero*. Otherwise, excellent answer. (+1)

Comment: @AlannRosas: Thanks for the catch. The problem when one of $a$ or $b$ is $0$ and the other is infinite is really the difficulty that the instructor's solution has to overcome, either by appealing to L'Hospital or estimating the size of the limiting quantity. The student's solution needs an extra justification as well, but it's simpler because one of the limits is nonzero, like you mentioned.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thank you let me wait for more replies...Tq again

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite:

$$  \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(- 2 x + \ln{\left(x \right)}\right)  = \color{red}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln{\left(x e^{- 2 x} \right)}} 
$$
Move the limit under the logarithm:
$$\color{black}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln{\left(x e^{- 2 x} \right)}} = \color{black}{\ln{\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} x e^{- 2 x} \right)}}$$
After:

$$\ln{\left(\color{black}{\lim_{x \to \infty} x e^{- 2 x}} \right)} = \ln{\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{2 x}} \right)}$$
Since we have an indeterminate form of type $∞/∞$
, we can apply the l'Hopital's rule observing that

$$\ln{\left(\color{black}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2 x}\right)}} \right)} = \ln{\left(\color{black}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{- 2 x}}{2}} \right)}\longrightarrow \ln (\to0^+)\longrightarrow -\infty$$

Hence:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(- 2 x + \ln{\left(x \right)}\right)=-\infty$$